# Correct video not playing when button 3 is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, debugging

How would this be debugged and fixed?

I am finding the code incredibly difficult to debug.

How would this issue be fixed in the code?

I want the code to work how it works in the **demo code**: https://jsfiddle.net/awht6u37/

Where this `data-id` works:

```
<button class="playSingle2 cover" type="button" data-container="play1" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></button>
```

How do I fix the problem that is in the code presently **after adding** the **answer code** that was **given below**?

Where the behavior in the demo code: https://jsfiddle.net/awht6u37/

The correct video appears here when clicking on `<button>` **#3**.

```
<div class="playButtonContainer with-curtain ">
  <button class="playSingle0 cover" data-container="play1"></button>
  <button class="playSingle1 cover" data-container="play1"></button>
  <button class="playSingle2 cover" data-container="play1" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></button>
</div>

function findPlayers() {
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".cover");
    const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrap");
    buttons.forEach(function addToPlayers(button) {
      players.push({
        "cover": button,
        "wrapper": wrapper
      });
    });
  }

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    players.add(".playSingle" + i, (playerVarsList[i] || {}));
  }
```

**Should work the same way** as **this code** here with 3 buttons that is written differently. https://jsfiddle.net/7xz6gw1b/

What in here would need to be written differently?

```
function findPlayers() {
    const allCovers = document.querySelectorAll(".cover");
    const allWrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".wrap");
    allCovers.forEach(function addToPlayers(cover, index) {
      players.push({
        "cover": cover,
        "wrapper": (index < allWrappers.length) ? allWrappers[index] : allWrappers[allWrappers.length - 1]
      });
    });
  }

//to add the player to all the play buttons
  let totalPlayButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-container="play1"]').length;

  //looping over all the play buttons and adding player to that
  for (let i = 0; i < totalPlayButtons; i++) {
    players.add(".playSingle" + i, (playerVarsList[i % (Object.keys(playerVarsList).length)] || {}));
  }
```

Where in the demo code clicking on `<button>` **#3** that has no playlist given to it, instead plays the video from its `data-id=""`

[image]

**To reproduce the issue:**

Here is the code with **3** buttons I am right now working on: https://jsfiddle.net/3htaxrse/

When I click on `<button>` **#3**

[image]

I am shown video from  **#1**

```
0: {
      playerVars: {
        playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g"
      }
    }, // Button 1
```

[image]

Instead this is the video that should be seen. `data-id="-Xgi_way56U"`

[image]

```
<div class="playButtonContainer with-curtain ">
  <button class="playSingle0 cover" data-container="play1"></button>
  <button class="playSingle1 cover" data-container="play1"></button>
  <button class="playSingle2 cover" data-container="play1" data-id="-Xgi_way56U"></button>
</div>
```

That is the problem I am trying to fix in the code I am working on.

How would the code with **3 buttons** that I am working on be adjusted so that, the **correct** video plays? https://jsfiddle.net/7xz6gw1b/

Is there a way to look at how the **demo code** is **written**, to be able to make the appropriate changes in the **other code**?

https://jsfiddle.net/7xz6gw1b/

Because in the demo code it works as it should.

**Demo Code**: https://jsfiddle.net/awht6u37/

Is looking at the **demo code** helpful at all?

Because it works in there.

**An attempt at fixing:**

Replacing this line:

```
players.add(".playSingle" + i, (playerVarsList[i % (Object.keys(playerVarsList).length)] || {}));
```

With this line:

```
players.add(".playSingle" + i, (playerVarsList[i] || {}));
```

Did not work.

**I just tried.**

It breaks button 3 when I do that: https://jsfiddle.net/vpjrsb9z/

No video appears at all when button 3 is clicked.

Maybe almost fixed?

The 1st video isn't being selected anymore, that is good.

[image]

Comment: Please read: [mcve]. The above is all but *minimal*.

Comment: I already removed so much, over 3,000 lines from the code.

Comment: Ashley, stop editing the question. if you've any comments regarding any answer, then comment on that respective answer. Not in the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem happens because in your source code, there are **multiple divs with the class "video"**. The code uses a div with the class "video" to transfer the video id from the button to the actual video player.

Because there are multiple divs with the class video this doesn't work.

One workaround would be to just delete your first div block with class "play2" and everything contained in that div. However, you are probably going to want to be able to have multiple independent instances of the video player setup on the same page, so we need to fix the code so that the correct div with class "Video" is used.

For that change the implementation of the click event handler for the buttons.

From:

```
const myVideo = document.querySelector('.video');

document.querySelectorAll('button.cover').forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    myVideo.dataset.id = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
  });
});
```

To:

```
document.querySelectorAll('button.cover').forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    let container=event.currentTarget.dataset.container;
    let myVideo = document.querySelector('.' + container + ' .video');
    myVideo.dataset.id = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
  });
});
```

We first get the "container" from the button that was clicked. Then we search for a div with class "video" that is inside another div with that container class.

Note that you don't need the global `myvideo` variable anymore.

---

Also change the code in `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` to its original state:

```
//to add the player to all the play buttons
let totalPlayButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-container="play1"]').length;

//looping over all the play buttons and adding player to that
for (let i = 0; i < totalPlayButtons; i++) {
        players.add(".playSingle" + i, (playerVarsList[i] || {}));
}
players.add(".playInitial", {});
```

---

Also, there is a bug with your exit button logic, but that is outside the scope of this question. Please ask another question if you are having problems there.

Comment: What is the bug in my exit button logic? How should I frame the question to ask it?

Comment: To be able to ask the question, I would need to know/understand what is wrong with it.

Comment: @Ashley I don't know what causes the exit button bug. It doesn't always behave as expected. The "X" sometimes remains after clicking it, If you can reproduce the issue, try to find out if you can find the cause. If you can't then create another question on Stackoverflow asking for help.

Comment: How do I fix this error in the code I am receiving now? https://jsfiddle.net/ju5Lqbws/ Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'wrapper')"

Comment: There is something in here that would need to be adjusted:   //to add the player to all the play buttons
  let totalPlayButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-container="play1"]').length;

  //looping over all the play buttons and adding player to that
  for (let i = 0; i < totalPlayButtons; i++) {
    players.add(".playSingle" + i, (playerVarsList[i] || {}));
  }

Comment: On Stackoverflow you have to create a new question for each separate problem/question you have. Don't ask for other issues. Stackoverflow is a questions/answers site, not an interactive help site.

Comment: To produce a minimal code example, I had to remove over 3,000 lines from it. After I added your code to it, it is now broken. ////// Where did I mess up?

Comment: The error happens because you added `<button class="playInitial cover spinner" type="button" data-container="play1" data-id="EK3h0IADYrQ">` to the source code. This increases `totalPlayButtons`. Change the way `totalPlayButtons` is calculated so that only the actual play buttons are counted, not the initial one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250642/discussion-between-ashley-and-nineberry).

Comment: Change the way totalPlayButtons is calculated so that only the actual play buttons are counted, not the initial one.
Means, how do I do that, make that change/edit in the code?

Comment: You were wrong: Code works now: https://jsfiddle.net/7bg249zu/   This one was supposed to be play2, not play1.  <button class="playInitial cover spinner" type="button" data-container="play2" data-id="EK3h0IADYrQ">
      <span class="color-circle"></span>
    </button>

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of places where array index is out of bound, that’s why it is not working.

Changes in **onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()** function:

```
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  let playerVarsList = {
    0: {
      playerVars: {
        playlist: "0dgNc5S8cLI,mnfmQe8Mv1g,-Xgi_way56U,CHahce95B1g"
      }
    },
    1: {
      playerVars: {
        listType: "playlist",
        list: "PLYeOyMz9C9kYmnPHfw5-ItOxYBiMG4amq"
      }
    }
  }
 //to add the player to all the play buttons
  let totalPlayButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-container="play1"]').length;

   //looping over all the play buttons and adding player to that
  for (let i = 0; i < totalPlayButtons; i++) {
    players.add(".playSingle" + i, (playerVarsList[i%(Object.keys(playerVarsList).length)] || {}));
  }
  players.add(".playInitial", {});
}
```

Changes in **findPlayers()** function

```
function findPlayers() {
    const allCovers = document.querySelectorAll(".cover");
    const allWrappers = document.querySelectorAll(".wrap");
    allCovers.forEach(function addToPlayers(cover, index) {
      players.push({
        "cover": cover,
        "wrapper": (index<allWrappers.length)?allWrappers[index]:allWrappers[allWrappers.length-1]
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250503/discussion-on-answer-by-ankit-the-1st-blue-play-button-shows-a-video-the-2nd-bl).

Comment: As was previously noted, comments are not for extended discussion. Please use the chat room ([linked above](/posts/comments/132073366)) for any further conversations about this post (_e.g._ specific feedback on this answer). Generally relevant information about your question should go _inside the question itself_ for current and future visitors to be able to fully understand your problem.